# Sumar y restar valores select2 y resultado en un input

Tags: jquery, laravel, select2

Hola tengo el siguiente select2 múltiple, donde básicamente, se muestra id factura y en texto el numero separado con una como el importe de ésta, quiero que al ir seleccionando o desseleccionando, me sume o me reste y el resultado (suma de importes), se vea reflejado en un input

```
                               
 <select data-pharaonic="select2" id="factura" name="factura[]" multiple="" style="width: 100%" class="form-select select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-select2-id="select2-data-factura">
    <option value="66">FCE-0004-00000041 ,7871401.92</option>
    <option value="67">FCE-0004-00000042 ,8141705.64</option>
</select>
</div>
```

me funciona solo para el primer elemento seleccionado, al seleccionar un segundo elemento me da error y no encuentro solución

```
 
 var dataMonto=0;
        $('#factura').on("select2:select", function (e) {            
            monto= e.params.data.text;            
            monto=monto.split(" ,")           
            monto=Number(monto[1]).toFixed(2);
            dataMonto=Number(dataMonto+monto);
            $('#cobrado').val(dataMonto);           
         });
         $('#factura').on("select2:unselect",function(e){
            monto= e.params.data.text;            
            monto=monto.split(" ,")   
            monto=Number(monto[1]).toFixed(2);
            $('#cobrado').val(dataMonto);
            dataMonto=Number(dataMonto-monto);
         });
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema con tu código es que estás utilizando una variable global `dataMonto` para almacenar el valor total de los importes seleccionados. Esta variable solo mantiene el valor del importe seleccionado anteriormente y no tiene en cuenta los importes seleccionados o deseleccionados más recientemente.

Para resolver este problema, deberás recorrer los elementos seleccionados y sumar sus importes cada vez que se seleccione o deseleccione un elemento. Una forma de hacer esto es utilizando la función `$.map()` de jQuery para obtener los valores de todos los elementos seleccionados y sumarlos.

Aquí te dejo una solución posible:

```
$('#factura').on("select2:select select2:unselect", function (e) {
  var dataMonto = 0;
  var selectedOptions = $('#factura').select2('data');
  $.each(selectedOptions, function(index, value) {
    var monto = value.text.split(" ,")[1];
    dataMonto += Number(monto);
  });
  $('#cobrado').val(dataMonto.toFixed(2));
});
```

En este código, el evento `select2:select select2:unselect` se dispara cada vez que se selecciona o deselecciona un elemento. Luego, se obtienen los valores de todos los elementos seleccionados utilizando la función `$('#factura').select2('data')`. Se recorren todos los elementos seleccionados con `$.each()`, se obtiene su importe y se suma a `dataMonto`. Finalmente, se actualiza el valor del input `#cobrado` con el valor total de `dataMonto` redondeado a dos decimales utilizando `toFixed(2)`.

Espero que esta solución te sea útil.

Answer (score 2):

Hola puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
const facturaSelect = document.getElementById("factura");
const resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");

facturaSelect.addEventListener("change", actualizarResultado);

function actualizarResultado() {
  let suma = 0;
  const opciones = facturaSelect.options;
  for (let i = 0; i < opciones.length; i++) {
    const valorOpcion = opciones[i].value;
    const importe = parseFloat(valorOpcion.split(",")[1]);
    if (opciones[i].selected) {
      suma += importe;
    } else {
      suma -= importe;
    }
  }
  resultado.value = suma.toFixed(2);
}
```

Acá lo que hago es recorrer todas las opciones del `SELECT`, y que sume cada opción seleccionada y que reste cada deseleccionada. Para detectar si alguna opción ha sido deseleccionada se puede utilizar la propiedad `selected`. Si esta es `TRUE` se suma, de lo contrario (`FALSE`) se resta y se va acumulando en la variable `SUMA`.